# I'm trying to create an auto-clicker and I cant get it to stop and start

Tags: python, function, tkinter, keyboard, pyautogui

I'm trying to create an auto-clicker.

I have tried various methods to get the auto click to start and stop with a certain key (hotkey) but no solution I came up with seems to work. When I press the hotkey button "a" nothing happens, It doesn't react in any way, and the keyboard thread that I have doesn't react either.

Im not sure what's wrong. I also want to start auto-clicking on the press and release of the hotkey but don't know how. Could someone help/fix the code?

Full Code Below

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import threading

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
#pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

# Window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title("X's AutoClicker")
root.configure(bg="White")

# Tabs
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.place(x=0, y=0)
tab1 = Frame(notebook, width=500, height=300)
tab2 = Frame(notebook, width=500, height=300)
notebook.add(tab1, text='  Menu  ')
notebook.add(tab2, text='  Settings  ')

# Variables
delay = 0
count = 1
repeat = IntVar()
repeat.set(1)
hotkey = 'a'
press_key = "Left"
single_double_var = StringVar()
single_double_var.set("Single")
single_double_drop = ["Single", "Double"]

# Functions
def none():
    return

def intervals():  # 1H = 3600 SECS, 1M = 60 SECS, 1S = 1S, 1S = 0.001 Mi
    global delay
    h = hour.get()
    m = minute.get()
    s = second.get()
    mi = millisecond.get()
    if h == '':
        h = "0"
    if m == '':
        m = "0"
    if s == '':
        s = "0"
    if mi == '':
        mi = "0"
    h_to_s = int(h) * 3600
    m_to_s = int(m) * 60
    s_to_s = int(s) * 1
    mi_to_s = int(mi) * 0.001
    delay = h_to_s + m_to_s + s_to_s + mi_to_s

def press_update():
    global press_key
    press_key = press_entry.get()

def hotkey_update():
    global hotkey
    hotkey = hotkey_entry.get()

def repeat_toggle():
    global count
    count += 1
    if count == 2:
        count = 0
        repeat.set(None)

def settings_select():
    notebook.select(tab2)


def autoclick():
    global clicks_amount, single_double_var2
    autoclick.status = "exit"
    
    while True:
        while autoclick.status == "exit":
            pass

        intervals()
        press_update()
        single_double_var2 = single_double_var.get()
        clicks_amount = str(click.get())
        if str(clicks_amount) != "":
            clicks_amount = int(clicks_amount)

            try:
                if repeat.get() == 1:
                    if single_double_var2 == "Single":
                        pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, duration=delay, button=press_key)

                    if single_double_var2 == "Double":
                        pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)
                        pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)

            except TclError:
                if single_double_var2 == "Single":
                    pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)

                if single_double_var2 == "Double":
                    pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)
                    pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks_amount, button=press_key)


def exit_program():
    def on_keyboard_press(event):
        if event.name == hotkey:
            print(event)
            print(autoclick.status)

            if autoclick.status == "pause":
                autoclick.status = "exit"
                
            if autoclick.status == "exit":
                autoclick.status = "run"

            elif autoclick.status == "run":
                autoclick.status = "exit"

    keyboard.on_press(on_keyboard_press)


threading.Thread(target=autoclick).start()
threading.Thread(target=exit_program).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Note: I removed all of the Tkinter front end of this program to leave out unnecessary code.